# Shortcuts key for Eclipse for Return - Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I was a Netbeans user for almost one year. Now, I´m changing my IDE to Eclipse and I´m learning Shortcuts Keys. In Netbeans I used to type "re", then hit Tab key to complete `return` keyword. How is this done in Eclipse?

Comment: Could to clarify what `re + tab key to introduce return` means? Do you mean generate a Java `return` statement or to introduce line feeds in your files?

Comment: Probably you want code completing - in Eclipse it is CTRL + SPACE, for example `ret` + CTRL + SPACE, is that what you wanted?

Comment: Although i didn't understand clearly what do you mean by _introducing return_ you can use CTRL + SPACE for **Content Assist**.You can view all the shortcut keys in eclipse from the tab   Window/ Preferences / General / Keys.

Comment: I don´t want to use Content Assist, because it gaves me different choices to select one (one of them is return). I Want to automatically write return when i made re + tab key, as I do in netbeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't think there is a predefined option for this, your best bet will be to create a custom **Java Editor Template**. In your Eclipse Preferences, under `Java > Editor > Templates`, you can create a new template with the following specifications:

```
Name: re
Context: Java statements
Automatically Insert: Checked
Pattern: return ${retVal:var('${return_type}')};
```

What this will do is you can type `re` and then bring up Content Assist using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. The very first proposal will be this template and it will be selected already. If you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it'll insert a line like the following:

```
return retVal;
```

At this point, there will be an outline around `retVal` and you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> again and it'll give you variables you can return that are in scope and match your method's return type or simply type what you want to return.

Comment: Thanks. I really don ´t Know how the raking of this site works. I made a simple question and receive -1? The person responsible for this has to give me an answer, because it´s absolutely nonsense and incentivate to not make any questions.

Comment: I'm not positive what the purpose of the -1 was. Looks like you received one vote to close the question due to it being "unclear." I gave your question a +1 since you clarified what you were looking for in the comments.